# migrate Android app from OrmLite to Room

Tags: android, ormlite, android-room

I have an Android app with a somewhat complex database (18 tables).  The app currently uses OrmLite to map and manage database objects.  I'd like to migrate the app incrementally to use Room.  I've read about [steps to migrate](https://medium.com/google-developers/incrementally-migrate-from-sqlite-to-room-66c2f655b377) an existing SQLite app to Room, which involves replacing `SQLiteOpenHelper` with Room's `SupportSQLiteOpenHelper`.  However, I don't think I could easily replace that within the OrmLite framework. Does anyone know if it's possible for OrmLite and Room to coexist in the same runtime, accessing the same SQLite database file?  What steps would I need to take to ensure the database is not corrupted between the two frameworks, other than the obvious transfer of entity classes from OrmLite to Room?

Thank you.